# Problema en C++ básico

Tags: c++

estoy aprendiendo a programar y para un trabajo debo crear un codigo, pero tengo un problema, ya he hecho unos trabajos parecidos antes pero no sé cual es el problema con las variables. 
En la linea cout<<"La clase del vehiculo es "; < error: expected primary-expression before '<<' token|

Gracias de antemano y disculpen si es algo muy bobo

```
int anio, peso, clase;
float tarifa;
cout<<"Ingrese el año del automovil";
cin>> anio;
cout<<"Ingrese el peso del automovil (lbs)";
cin>> peso;


if (anio<=1970){
    if (peso<=2700){
    clase = 1;
    tarifa = 16.50;
    cout<<"La clase del vehiculo es "; <<clase; cout<<" y la tarifa es de $"; <<tarifa; //acá tengo el problema 

    }
}
return 0;
```

}

Comment: Tu problema esta donde dice "clase"

Comment: Voto para cerrar esta pregunta como tema no relacionado porque el usuario no parece tener claro el lenguaje de programación que está usando.

Answer (score 5):

Te respondo por esta vía porque los comentarios se me quedan pequeños.

`cout` y `cin` son clases propias de C++, no de C. O bien tu pregunta está mal etiquetada (haces referencia al lenguaje C en vez de a C++) o bien estás confundiendo los lenguajes a la hora de codificar.

Si es lo primero te sugiero editar la pregunta para que haga referencia a C++ en vez de a C. En este caso comentarte que el error se produce porque estás finalizando la instrucción antes de tiempo al intercalar un punto y coma:

```
cout<<"La clase del vehiculo es "; <<clase; cout<<" y la tarifa es de $"; <<tarifa;
                                 ^ AQUI!!!                              ^ y AQUI!!!
```

La solución es tan sencilla como eliminar esos separadores:

```
cout<<"La clase del vehiculo es " <<clase;
cout<<" y la tarifa es de $" <<tarifa;
```

E incluso si lo prefieres puedes compactarlo en una única instrucción:

```
cout<<"La clase del vehiculo es " <<clase
    <<" y la tarifa es de $" <<tarifa;
```

Si lo que sucede es que te has confundido de lenguaje al codificar te cuento que para interactuar con el usuario vía consola en C puedes hacer uso de las funciones `printf` y `scanf` de la librería `stdio.h`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int anio;
printf("Ingrese el año del automovil");
scanf("%i",&anio);
```

Si resulta que deberías estar programando en C, has de saber que el compilador está aceptando librerías propias de C++ porque tu compilador no es de C sino de C++ (Y en gran medida el código C es compilable en C++). Deberías tener cuidado con esto para no llevarte sorpresas desagradables al llevar tu código a clase.

Answer (score 1):

Al momento de imprimir el cotenido de las variables estas incluyendo unos punto y comas que no deberian ir, ya que estas indicando que cuando llege el punto y coma la impresion del cout deberia terminar y despues continuanas imprimiendo pero sin volver a utilizar el cout por lo tanto tu codigo termina fallando.

Codigo corregido

```
int main()
{
    int anio, peso, clase;
    float tarifa;
    cout<<"Ingrese el año del automovil";
    cin>> anio;
    cout<<"Ingrese el peso del automovil (lbs)";
    cin>> peso;


    if (anio<=1970){
        if (peso<=2700){
        clase = 1;
        tarifa = 16.50;
        cout<<"La clase del vehiculo es "<<clase;
        cout<<" y la tarifa es de $"<<tarifa; //acá tengo el problema

        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Para mas informacion sobre el objeto cout puedes mirar el siguiente enlace http://www.pablin.com.ar/computer/cursos/c1/cout.html

Comment: Me corregi, y disculpenme pofavor. Si estaba confundido, programo en C++. Gracias por ayudarme a ver el error, ya me funcionó y lo tendré en cuenta siempre.

Comment: @DiegoPatiño, si la respuesta del usuario Rene Garnica ha solucionado tu problema, te recomiendo [aceptar su respuesta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).